# How to take the first row matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to ask if I have a matrix for example :
a=[1 2 3 ; 1 3 4 ; 4 5 7 ]
and how to take only the first row that is [1 2 3]. thank you .

Comment: This question has 13000 views and is closed as not constructive?

Answer (score 18):

a(1,:)

This means (first row, all columns)